# If available why does the processor not use a clustered index scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

So I have this structure on a user table:

[image]

But if I run the following code:

```
select count(*) 
from WH.dbo.tb_DimUserAccount
```

It seems to go for the Non-Unique Non-Clustered index `ix_DimUserAccount_UserType`:

[image]

This is the Index Scan:

[image]

Why doesn't it go for a scan of `ix_DimUserAccount_Unique` ? Should I change my code to somehow use a different index?

Comment: The clustered index is the whole table; the non-clustered index is a slice of the table. If you had a choice to count all the cars in the parking lot manually, or could accurately rely on counting the keys in the valet stand, which would *you* do?

Comment: ok - thanks Aaron. In some execution plans I see scans of clustered indexes...will that be because it is the cheapest route it can find? If it is expensive to scan the clustered index then what is the point of this sort of index? (I'm probably testing the phrase "there is no such thing as a silly question")

Comment: Different types of indexes are useful for different things. Sometimes you will see a clustered index scan because you selected enough columns to make a non-clustered index scan (even on a skinnier index), plus lookups to get the other columns from the table, more expensive. Or because your table doesn't have an index that supports the where clause for the query.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - so effectively a CI stores an ordered copy of the whole table; therefore hitting a thin NCI is quite often first prize.

Comment: I don't know if I'd say "quite often" - it simply depends. Far too many variables to make broad statements about what is always or usually the best way to satisfy a variety of queries. If you're just performing a `COUNT`, yes, SQL Server will generally prefer to scan the skinniest index you have (that isn't filtered). Better yet is to derive counts from metadata (e.g. `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`) - then you don't have to scan the table at all.

Comment: "thickness" is determined by the combined size of the data types of the columns included in the index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the non clustered index is probably narrower than the clustered index and it is cheaper to scan than the clustered index (fewer pages to read).

The NCI leaf pages just contain values for the index keys and any included columns. The clustered index leaf pages need to contain values (or pointers to the values) for all columns in the table.

Thus the clustered index will (assuming equal fill factors) generally fit fewer rows per page than an NCI (except for the case where an NCI includes all columns in the table)

Comment: +1 this is good stuff Martin - must admit when folks start mentioning leafs and pages I start assuming its information I don't understand and will never understand! - but I'm on a week course with Itzik in just over a week's time so maybe these terms will start to become less scary and a little more familiar.

Comment: @whytheq - Wow. Very lucky. I'm sure you'll learn loads on a week with Itzik.